# Motherboard refuses to boot from SATA HDD

Tags: hard-drive, boot, motherboard, sata

*I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this. It seemed like the closest fit in the SX sites, and [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105221/create-a-stack-exchange-site-for-pc-hardware) seemed to suggest it was the right place. Here goes!*

My computer has recently decided not to boot from my hard drives, though it seems to recognise both of them. After the BIOS loads, it shows me this:

[image: 2]

I'm certain the drives still work, since I can occasionally boot after changing all the cables around - but then I come back the next day and the same configuration fails to boot.

I wanted to take the chance to ask: how does a motherboard usually determine where to boot from? In this case, it looks like the motherboard found both hard drives, but just ignored the fact that the 60GB drive has Windows on. Or are there other factors that might prevent the drive from being bootable, even if it is 'working'?

EDIT: Of course, I should mention. Motherboard is a GA-MA790XT-UD4P, the hard drives are a 1TB Samsung and a 60GB Intel 330 series SSD.

Comment: Reset bios to defaults - make sure the virus protection isn't enabled if the board has it - remove all cards. Try again. (There are quite a few things to try out) - let me know if that works - if not we will try something else

Comment: Remove all USB devices and try another keyboard if you have one

Comment: ATA 133? Are you using a SATA to IDE converter by chance with the SSD?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I'll give that a go once this assignment is done ;). Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @kobaltz No, just the SATA cables that came with the mobo plugged into two of its SATA2 ports. Seeing ATA on there is probably a bad sign?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I tried booting today, after removing all USB devices, and it worked. Not sure if it was just the time delay.